# get event's fired from iframe to parent

Tags: javascript, html

when defining mouse down, move and up for an iframe and it's parent, and, doing mouse-down on the iframe and moving outside of iframe prevents the parent to fire mouse-move event, so `e.target` is always is  tag element. what I want is when the pointer is outside of iframe and on the parent, it shows the element under the mouse pointer. is there any workaround for this?

edited: this is the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-boyd-54ys9?file=/index.html) that you can reproduce the issue I have.

1. place mouse pointer inside iframe
2. perform a mouse-down and keep it down
3. move the pointer into the parent region( like drag and drop from iframe to parent)
4. while the mouse is still down read the console, the output is "mouse move in ifrmae" and e.target points to iframe's  element.

what I expect: the output should be "moving in parent".

if we do the same steps from parent to iframe we don't have this problem.

Comment: What have you tried and what issues are you running in to? Consider providing an [Minimal Reproducible Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have updated my questions